# Cloud PubSub 'VIEW MESSAGES' - can not select push subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We ran into this issues a few times and hope to find a workaround. 
[screenshot of Cloud PubSub web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLAHn.png)
As in the picture, the `PubSub` topic has a push subscription on it. When 'VIEW MESSAGES' was clicked, the side panel seemed to allow the user to choose a subscription. But when the user clicked on it, it was not showing the subscription. As a result, the user was not able to 'view messages'.

Is the type of subscription related to this issue or is this functionality not available? If it is related, is there a way to see messages for a topic with only a push subscription?

Answer (score 4):

A push subscription don't stack the message. Each time there is a message, the push subscription sent it to the HTTP endpoint. Because of this, the subscription is always "empty".(*This is not exactly true, the not acked message are in memory and are retried until the reception of HTTP code 2XX of the TTL expiration (7 days by default). But there is nothing really stored, at rest*)

At the opposite, the pull subscription stack the message until the polling by a client. By the way, you can see the messages stacked.

When I debug a push subscription, especially for seeing what is the structure, the type of message and to validate this, I create a pull subscription in addition and I look into it the messages published in the topic.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. The dropdown appeared red with a message "Subscription is required". It is requiring a pull subscription.

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate statement of the difference between push and pull. It is not true that "there is nothing really stored." Messages _are_ stored to ensure they can get redelivered up to the 7 day deadline. It is just that a push subscriptions do not return messages on pull requests because they are in "push" mode. If you change the "push" subscription to a "pull" subscription, then the "view messages" feature would start to return messages.

Comment: that is why aws sqs is much better :) pull or push at least you can view it all